# Extracting a part of lines matching a pattern

Tags: bash

I have a configuration file and need to parse out some values using bash

Ex. Inside config.txt

```
some_var= Not_needed
tests= spec1.rb spec2.rb spec3.rb
some_other_var= Also_not_needed
```

Basically I just need to get "spec1.rb spec2.rb spec3.rb" WITHOUT all the other lines and "tests=" removed from the line.

I have this and it works, but I'm hoping there's a much more simple way to do this.

```
while read run_line; do
if [[ $run_line =~ ^tests=* ]]; then
  echo "FOUND"
  all_selected_specs=`echo ${run_line} | sed 's/^tests= /''/'`
fi
done <${config_file}
echo "${all_selected_specs}"
```

Comment: Why don't you just run the sed command on the whole file with `sed -n 's/.../.../p'`?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean, unfortunately I don't use shell scripting a lot.

Comment: `man sed` should help clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work too

```
grep "^tests" ${config_file} | sed -e "s/^tests= //"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
all_selected_specs=$(awk -F '= ' '$1=="tests" {print $2}' "$config_file")
```

Using a field separator of `"= "`, look for lines where the first field is `tests` and print the second field.

Answer (score 0):

How about `grep` and `cut`?

```
all_selected_specs=$(grep "^tests=" "$config_file" | cut -d= -f2-)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
all_selected_specs=$(awk '/^tests/{sub(/.*= /,"");print}' Input_file)
```

searching for string tests which comes in starting of a line then substituting that line's all values till (= ) to get all spec values, once it is substituted then we are good to get the spec values so printing that line. Finally saving it's value to variable with $(awk...).